# How to install Airnef on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: camera, wifi-direct

I have downloaded airnef (http://www.testcams.com/airnef/) a camera to computer wireless utility but am unable to install on Ubuntu 16.04, any help on simple installation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did both, the double click on airnef did not work, then I right clicked and select run but still nothing happened , then in the terminal I installed python-tk  and  run the command python airnef.pyw but this reply     python cant open file 'airnef.pyw' : [Errno:2] No such file or directory

Comment: dude i have told you to go to the directory where you have extracted and then run `python airnef.pyw` . you can change directory in terminal by running `cd path/to/your/directory`

Answer (score 0):

To run it, simply extract the downloaded archive and double click the "airnef" executable.

For Linux 32bit (also works for 64bit obviously, if you prefer using the python source instead of the binary), firstly install python-tk by running

`sudo apt-get install python-tk`

once you installed python-tk, In the folder where you've extracted it, run the following command to start the application

`python airnef.pyw`

Hope it helps

Comment: I did both, the double click on airnef did not work, then I right clicked and select run but still nothing happened , then in the terminal I installed python-tk  and  run the command python airnef.pyw but this reply     python cant open file 'airnef.pyw' : [Errno:2] No such file or directory

Comment: because python couldn't find the file airnef.pyw , plz go to the folder where you have extracted it. you can do it by `cd path/to/your/directory`. Also you can go to the directory where  `airnef.pyw` is located, then right click and select  `open in terminal` . once you are in the folder, run `python airnef.pyw`.

Comment: I did cd Downloads and enter Downloads

Comment: I entered the Downloads by cd Download then cd airnef to enter in airnef directory both in Downloads and in airnef directory I wrote both the commands airnef.pyw and python airnef.pyw .Then i checked all the directories inside airnef directory with these commands nothing happened. Lastly in the diresctory of airnef I wrote python to enter in the python there I write these commands nothing happened.

Comment: hey i said download python source if you prefer python. If you run this command in airnef binary, this won't work. download python source from the website and then run `python airnef.pyw`

Comment: I had installed python tk two days back via terminal

Comment: dude are you even following what i said. download python source from airnef website, the one you specified in your question.

Comment: Maybe my ubuntu 16.04 LTS is 32 bit and it is only for 64 bit.

Comment: hey but you followed wrong. Download python source from http://www.testcams.com/airnef/

Comment: extract, change the directory and run command

Comment: Thanks solved, I changes the name and copied the the pyhthon source file folder and  in the airnef folder and run the command  python airnef.pyw the software runs now

Answer (score 0):

solved, I rename and copied the the pyhthon source file folder on the website and  in the airnef folder and run the command  python airnef.pyw the software runs now.